# belongsToMany with 4 tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables with relations like on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hitbj.png).
I have also 2 functions in User model:

```
public function getUserSchools(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Schools::class, 'user_has_schools', 'user_id', 'school_id');
}

public function getUserRoles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Roles::class, 'user_has_schools', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

They work fine, but I want to merge results of them - I need to get schools of this user with his role in every school (for example: [Primary School, Teacher], [High School, Boss], etc.).
How can I reach that result? Maybe this is a trivial question, but I'm just starting my adventure with Laravel. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the Laravel polymorphic relationship 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

sample :

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the tags for the post.
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

don't mind the sample methods

```
class Tag extends Model
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'taggable');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'taggable');
    }

    public function links()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Links', 'taggable');
    }

    public function forum()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Forums', 'taggable');
    }
}
```